# Java. Compare webpages structure (dom) similarity. 

Tags: java, html, dom, similarity

Is there a library (for java) that compares similarity between web pages (HTML, dom similarity)?

In my application I want to classify links of a website.
For example:
`group 1: Product detail page
group 2: Category page` (for online shopping sites, etc.).

For such a classification html structure (dom) similarity is the best way I think. Please help regarding this.

Comment: It seems quite too ambiguous and specific for it to be there a library for this (the definition of "similarity" being the main source of ambiguity).

Comment: "a libray" or "a function of a libray" or "a simple java application" will be enough for my application.

Comment: If you want help designing such an application, you need to post more details and explain what have you tried/what didn't work. Again, don't count on something preexisting.

Comment: maybe [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) can help you

Comment: I use jsoup to extract data. 
Example;
For a product detail page, extracting products' name, image, price etc. I dont know if jsoup can be used to compare dom similarity.

Comment: Might be a bit on the heavy side. But this paper describes some algorithms and techniques that you may be able to use to develop a solution. https://e-reports-ext.llnl.gov/pdf/305392.pdf

Comment: http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/ - another link worth looking at. You might find that the size of the textual content , and the quantity of text blocks between the two pages types is substantial, and thus gives at least some fuzzy logic to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you ask but if the HTMl is XML valid you can use [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/), it's [very simple](http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/xml-comparison-tutorial-using-xmlunit/) to compare similarity with it.